# Replace backslash with slash using sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I need to replace `\` with `/`.

I have a file that has:

```
test\test2\test3\test4
```

I tried

```
VRS_Ruta=$(cat ruta.lst | sed 's/^.//g' | sed 's,/,///,g' )
```

output

```
test\test2\test3\test4
```

I need:

```
test/test2/test3/test4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
 sed 's/\\/\//g'
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  Slightly shorter alternative: `sed 's|\\|/|g'`