# Back-slashes are disappearing from user input (read -p)

Tags: bash, replace, backslash

In my script I'm requesting to the user to specify a path. Because I'm on Windows I want to replace all `\` to `/`. This would be a easy task to do, but I'm having some troubles:

```
read -p "Please, type/paste the working path (folder) you wish to link this scripts: " working_dir
```

> I already did what this answers said:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/6853452/3286975
>
> `tr '\\' '/'`
>
> https://superuser.com/a/1068082/634144
>
> `home_mf="${home//\\//}"`
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/50220624/3286975
>
> `sed 's/\\/\//g'`
>
> But I have no luck. This is what I do:
>
> ```
> working_dir=$(echo "$working_dir" | <some of the pipe I typed before>)
> echo $working_dir
> ```

**EDIT:**

All the quoted text is not useful for the question. I thought that the problem was here. But echoing $working_dir under `read -p`command:

```
read -p "Please, type/paste the working path (folder) you wish to link this scripts: " working_dir
echo $working_dir
```

Output this:

[image: ...]

Why are backslashes disapearing? My logic thinks that `B` and `G` should be escaped also, or I'm wrong?

Comment: `"${home//\\//}"` should work fine. What is output of `declare -p home` ?

Comment: Instead of `<some of the pipe I typed before>` please show exactly what you tried and the rest of your `setup.sh` if it isn't too large. The error doesn't even look like it has anything to do with the operation you're questioning, but hard to tell.

Comment: Oh god, @anubhava I thought the problem was on the replace. Is on the input. I will edit the entire question.

Comment: Example, typed into the `bash` prompt: `x=\\a\\b\\c ; x=$(echo "$x" | tr '\\' '/'); echo $x` produces `/a/b/c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `-r` switch of `read` to *not allow backslashes to escape any characters* (as written in `help read`).

So this will work:

```
read -rp "Please, type/paste the working path (folder) you wish to link this scripts: " working_dir
working_dir=${working_dir//\\//}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was useful. I didn't know about the -r param on `read` command.

Comment: This should be the default! so _always use `read` with the `-r` switch, **unless you really want to allow the backslash to be an escape character!**_

Comment: Ok, I will take care of this.

Comment: There's an additional potential complication: some versions of `echo` will attempt to interpret escapes (backslashes), so even if they're in the variable correctly, they may not be printed. Instead of `echo`, use `printf '%s\n' "$working_dir"`.